# I am getting issue on accordion click event in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created one page in that there is on button like MORE.if i click on MORE next page will display.In next page there are 5   accordion  tab created..the issue is that  accordion  tab click event is not working.Please help me..

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>DUMMY</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

            <style>
          .accordion-toggle{
        display:inline-block;
            width:100%;
        }
            </style>


        </head>
        <body class="blue-skin">

         <div class="wrapper">

            <!-- SECTION -->
            <section id="home">
                <div class="wrap inverse bg-dark vpadding-strong anima">


                </div>
            </section>

            <section id="advs">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <header class="content-header"></header>

                    <article id="fumeExhaustSystem" class="container_12 content center">
                        <div class="grid_1"></div>
                        <div class="grid_10">
                            <div class="grid_6">
                                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
                                    <a href="#" data-popup="work-popup-2" class="button"><span>More</span></a>
                                </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="grid_1"></div>
                    </article>



                    <footer class="content-footer"></footer>
                </div>
            </section>



        </div> <!-- /wrapper -->



        <div class="overlay"></div> <!-- overlay layer -->

        <!-- POPUP: portfolio -->

            <div id="work-popup-2" class="popup work-popup">
                <a href="#" class="pclose"></a>
                <div class="slides-container fullslider">
                    <ul class="sliderwrap">
                        <li><div class="bgimg"><img src="images/slides/slide-3.jpg" alt=""></div></li>
                        <li><div class="bgimg"><img src="images/slides/slide-4.jpg" alt=""></div></li>
                        <li><div class="bgimg"><img src="images/slides/slide-5.jpg" alt=""></div></li>
                        <li><div class="bgimg"><img src="images/slides/slide-6.jpg" alt=""></div></li>
                        <li><div class="bgimg"><img src="images/slides/slide-9.jpg" alt=""></div></li>
                    </ul>
                    <a href="#" class="slide-prev slide-arrow"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="slide-next slide-arrow"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="container_12 vpadding">
                    <div class="grid_3">
                        <h2> System</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid_9">
                        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."


        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                  1. 
                </a><i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down  pull-right"></i>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
                   2. 
                </a><i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up  pull-right"></i>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

         <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
                   3. 
                </a><i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up  pull-right"></i>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">
               "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
              </div>
            </div>
          </div> <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapsefour">
                   4. 
                </a><i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up  pull-right"></i>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapsefour" class="panel-collapse collapse">

              <div class="panel-body">
                <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapsefive">
                  5. 
                </a><i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up pull-right"></i>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapsefive" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>


        <script>
        function toggleChevron(e) {
            $(e.target)
                .prev('.panel-heading')
                .find("i.indicator")
                .toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up');
        }
        $('#accordion').on('hidden.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);
        $('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);
        </script>



        <script src="js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.plugins.js"></script>
        <script src="js/custom.js"></script>


        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Not able to see any accordion code here. :) 
are you using bootstrap accordions.

Comment: yes...there is 1,2,3,4,5 like that tab is in code

Comment: sorry for above comment was having Javascript disabled in browser at first because was testing something

Comment: is there any one here to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is that you are collapsing div on click of anchor tag.

```
<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
```

and it's working fine, but maybe you want it to be opened on click of whole slide,
you can do it with CSS workaround by making anchor spread on whole clickable panel.

see the attached fiddle for more info

Updated Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RockRathore/f6au4bn9/3/

Comment: do you saw the fiddle link i attached?
Its working fine in fiddle

Comment: yes i saw its working there but why its not working in my sublime text.

Comment: Then please check your files are they included properly, this can be case sometimes

Comment: Files are propre i checked

Comment: i mean bootstrap files, i don't see them included in your code

Comment: Mr.Rock, i tried your code its working but the issue is there is one form in that One button name is MORE when i click on MORE next page will open in that accordion tab click event not working i tried your code there .if i run you code in single page its working.

Comment: Sorry but i am unable to understand what you are trying to accomplish here, According to your question you said that clicking on tab panel does not work, but i made it work in the fiddle link i posted. Can you elaborate the above comment a bit more.

Comment: Thats correct  according to my question clicking on tab panel does not work but its working on single page.i have two forms in first form there is MORE button after click on MORE then accordion tab is not working  on second form

Comment: Mr.Rock ,Please check below site http://test.hybreed.co/products.html       you will understand my question

Comment: Please help me Mr.ROCK

Comment: @Narenverma 
sorry but was busy with some of my work.
Coming to the point i saw your link, the issue is that on hidden element jQuery is not applied, try using visibility:hidden instead of display:none on your popup.

Comment: Use this code to make it work

$(".panel-heading").on("click",function(){
$(".collapse.in").removeClass("in");
 $(this).next(".collapse").toggleClass("in")
});